# Heuristics for lightweighted "cubic" spanning trees

Tags: graph-theory, heuristics, spanning-tree

I have the problem of calculating a good approximation of the minimimum-weight spanning tree with vertex-degrees in $\lbrace 1,3\rbrace$ of a complete symmetric graph, without parallel edges or self-loops, with $n=2k$ vertices.

> **Question:**
>
> which heuristics for the problem of finding a good approximation to the minimum-weight spanning tree with vertex-degrees $1$ and $3$ of a complete weighted graph are known?

To clarify: I am *not* looking for "*spanning trees of regular graphs*" and also not for "*spanning trees with many leaf nodes*"; that is what googling "regular spanning tree" brings up.

Comment: I'd conjecture that no good approx guarantee can be achieved.  In an unweighted graph, deciding if there is a $\{1, 2\}$-spanning tree is NP-hard (that's the Hamiltonian path problem).  This is used to show that finding a min-weight $\{1, 2\}$-spanning tree in a complete graph, i.e. TSP, can't be approximated by essentially any ratio (by replacing non-edges with edges of huge weight).  The same ideas should apply to $\{1, 3\}$-spanning trees.  It's probably NP-hard to find one in unweighted graphs, making the weighted complete version inapproximable.  Requires proof though.

Comment: Of course the inapproximability for $\lbrace 1, 2\rbrace$ edge weights is plausible, but there are also situations where the edgeweights allow for good approximation ratios, most prominently the planar Euclidean TSP and I am looking for heursitics for the problem stated as the above question that work well in specific situations.

Answer (score 0):

> **This should rather be seen as comment!**

meanwhile some ideas came to my mind that I'd like to share in hope to provoke answers to my question.

$1$st idea:
**Tweak Prim's MST algorithm**

- start with a single edge
- while there are undiscovered vertices

  - add to the $\lbrace 1,3\rbrace$-tree the pair $(\lambda_i, u_j).(\lambda_i, u_j)$ of edges of lightest weightsum that are adjacent to the same leaf node $\lambda_i$ and undiscovered vertices $u_j$ and $u_k$.

The complexity should be $O(n^2\log\,n)$ and I'm convinced that that heuristic must already be known.

$2$nd idea: **"Wavefront expansion"**

- start with a single edge or a claw graph $K_{1,3}$
- while there are undiscovered vertices

  - temporarily split the leaf-vertices
  - optimally match the copies of the leaf vertices to the set of undiscovered vertices
  - add the edges of that optimal matching to the $\lbrace1,3\rbrace$-tree.

The complexity is likely $O(n^3)$ and also that algorithm isn't very sophisticated and should have been mentioned already.